# Different pronunciations of "disputes"

Tags: pronunciation

Recently I have come across an [outtake from a YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Jwo5qc78QU&t=2410s) about different pronunciations of the word "disputes" depending on the context. According to my understanding from that video:

- *"This will lead to disputes"* (noun) is pronounced as *d**iss**-pjutes* while
- *"He disputes whether the laws are valid"* (verb) is pronounced as *dis-pj**uu**tes*

where the bolded parts are what is emphasized in pronunciation.

I've not been aware of the second pronunciation before and couldn't find any answers online about why, how or when that would be used.

When would I put emphasis on the *iss* and when to put it on the *u*? Does this differ between American and British English?

Comment: First: _the noun_, second: _the verb_. Typical in UK speech, I don't know about elsewhere.

Comment: ***Diss**-pute* does not sound at all familiar to this native speaker of American English. Only *dis-**pute***.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum - like I said, typical in British speech.

Comment: Have you tried checking a dictionary? Most major ones provide pretty good pronunciation guidance.